# Unescape HTML code from JavaScript function in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, escaping

I have a ruby19 scraper fetching next pages like ajax in browser does and these next pages are javascripts - something like:

```
...DOM.appendContent(this, HTML(\"\\u003cdiv class=\\\"...\\\">...
```

I am looking for some easy way how to unescape the HTML content to be able to feed it to Nokogiri - to get `<div class="...">...` from `\\u003cdiv class=\\\"...\\\">...`

Answer (score 0):

Try `CGI::unescapeHTML(html_escaped_string)`

For more info check the Ruby docs:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML